# How to prevent device from hanging when fetching all Persistent IDs and asset URLs of song list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

I want an array of persistent IDs from song list. I know how to get the persistent ID of any song, but retrieving `MPMediaItem`s one by one and fetching their persistent IDs takes a large amount of time and hangs the device.

My code to retrieve persistent id:

```
for (MPMediaItem *item in itemArray) {
    NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSNumber *persistentID = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    if (assetUrl != nil) {
        [localMedias addObject:assetUrl];
        [saveQueue addToQueue:persistentID];
    }
}
```

Hangs device when song list has over 500 songs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally any operation you perform that hangs the device should be performed on a background queue. There are two ways to do this: [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) and [NSOperationQueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html). Since we don't need any of the extra features NSOperationQueue provides to solve your problem, we'll use GCD.

First, let's perform your code on a background queue.

```
// show user that app is doing background work somehow

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (MPMediaItem *item in itemArray) {
        NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        NSNumber *persistentID = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        if (assetUrl != nil) {
            [localMedias addObject:assetUrl];
            [saveQueue addToQueue:persistentID];
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI to show user background work is done
    });
});
```

This will prevent the device from hanging, but it isn't perfect. If we want to perform this task in more than one location, we'll end up copy-pasting code, [which is bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). So let's wrap this in a method.

```
-(void)fetchPersistentIDsFromSongList {
    // show user that app is doing background work somehow

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        for (MPMediaItem *item in itemArray) {
            NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
            NSNumber *persistentID = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
            if (assetUrl != nil) {
                [localMedias addObject:assetUrl];
                [saveQueue addToQueue:persistentID];
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // update UI to show user background work is done
        });
    });
}
```

However, we run into some problems here. If we call this method, we have no guarantee that the fetch will be complete before the next line of code runs (see `dispatch_async` for more details). Also, assuming `localMedias` is an `NSMutableArray`, it may not be safe to fetch items from it while the fetch is still in progress. What we need is a way to tell whether or not the fetch has completed, but we still need the fetch itself to be performed on a background queue. What we need is to add a completion handler to our method in the form of a [block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html). ([See here for block syntax.](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)) Also, to prevent read/write conflicts, we won't return the array until the fetch is fully complete. But because we're doing everything asynchronously, we can't return it using conventional `return` statements, so we'll pass it in as a parameter to the completion block.

```
-(void)fetchPersistentIDsFromSongListWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *results))completion {
    // show user that app is doing background work somehow

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // initialize container for results
        NSMutableArray *localMedias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[itemArray count]];

        // fetch persistent ID from each item and save to results array
        for (MPMediaItem *item in itemArray) {
            NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
            NSNumber *persistentID = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
            if (assetUrl != nil) {
                [localMedias addObject:assetUrl];
                [saveQueue addToQueue:persistentID];
            }
        }

        // perform completion block and update UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // update UI to show user background work is done

            if(completion) {
                completion(localMedias);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can call this method, save the results in the completion block, and be guaranteed safety from the horrible debugging situations that multithreading can cause. Also, with regards to completion handlers, the general convention I've seen is to perform all completion blocks on the main queue unless you specify a queue as a parameter in the method, in which case the completion block should be performed on that queue.

```
[self fetchPersistentIDsFromSongListWithCompletion:^void (NSArray *results){
    // assume self.songIDs exists and is an NSArray
    self.songIDs = [results copy];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching on a background thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (MPMediaItem *item in itemArray) {
        NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        NSNumber *persistentID = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        if (assetUrl != nil) {
            [localMedias addObject:assetUrl];
            [saveQueue addToQueue:persistentID];

        }}

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI
    });
});
```